# Me podrian ayudar con este Error? Estoy trabajando con el motor de base de datos Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

El problema que tengo es que al momento de colocar 'CHECK'. en el campo **ubicacion** . Me gustaria saber como le hago para que solo me permita ingresar valores 'E00 hasta E99'.
**El error esta al momento de insertar**

> ORA-02290: check constraint (SQL_AZNYSDNXYBSDOGUWFHSQJQHUU.SYS_C0015166257) violated ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

````
```
    CREATE TABLE mascota(
        id_mascota int,
        nombre varchar2(60),
        especie char(1) CHECK (especie IN('P','G')),
        sexo char(1) CHECK (sexo IN('M','H')),
        ubicacion char(3) CHECK (ubicacion LIKE 'E[0-9][0-9]'),
        estado char(1) CHECK (estado IN ('A','B')),

        CONSTRAINT pk_mascota__id_mascota PRIMARY KEY(id_mascota)
    );

    INSERT INTO mascota VALUES(1,'Budy','P','M','E05','B');

    SELECT * FROM mascota;
```
````

[image: estos son los registros que necesito ingresar en la tabla mascota.]

Comment: Podrías al menos postear el mensaje de error?. Por otro lado, trata de no escribir todo en mayúsculas, da la impresión que estás gritando

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor no escribas en mayusculas, parece que esta gritando. Te creemos que da error, ahora, seria interesante que nos digas que error te da. Ese insert esta mal, lo valores numericos no van entre comillas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta linea:

```
ubicacion char(3) CHECK (ubicacion LIKE 'E[0-9][0-9]'),
```

Le dice que el constrains tiene que ser algo de la forma E[0-9][0-9], pero no como una expresion regular, si no exactamente como eso. Como vos queres que esa columna matchee con una expresion regular, entonces la sentencia no es asi, se deberia escribir de esta forma:

```
ubicacion char(3) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(ubicacion,'E[0-9][0-9]')),
```

fuente: [Click Aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501)

Comment: voy a probarlo :)

Comment: Funciono de Maravillas.. Mil Gracias :D

Comment: Una buena pregunta lleva a una respuesta correcta. Tomate siempre el tiempo de construir una buena pregunta para que la gente que puede ayudarte pueda entender tu problema. Prueba todo y da toda la informacion posible. Que suerte que puede ayudarte @AronAlmanza